# unable to connect to postgres from podman

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm, podman

I am trying to connect to my postgres instance which is running at port 5001 but the connection code is returning the error: **[error] failed to initialize database, got error failed to connect to `host=localhost user=admin database=contactsdb`: failed to receive message (unexpected EOF)**

Podman script

> podman run --name mypostgres -p 50001:5001 -e POSTGRES_DB=contactsdb -e POSTGRES_USER=admin -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin123 -d postgres

Here's my connection code

```
    dsn:="host=localhost user=admin password=admin123 dbname=contactsdb port=50001"     
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})    
    if err!=nil{
        fmt.Println("Could not Connect")    
    } else{
        fmt.Println("Successfully connected",db)
    }
```

Here's my postgres container:

```
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                              COMMAND               CREATED            STATUS            PORTS                    NAMES
a238196fb656  docker.io/library/mysql:latest     mysqld                8 hours ago        Up 8 hours        0.0.0.0:33406->3306/tcp  mysq2
4ee241546da5  docker.io/library/adminer:latest   php -S [::]:8080 ...  8 hours ago        Up 8 hours        0.0.0.0:48088->8080/tcp  adminui
e7bee47ab8ac  docker.io/library/postgres:latest  postgres              About an hour ago  Up About an hour  0.0.0.0:50001->5001/tcp  mypostgres
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose the container to the host’s network by adding `--network host` to your `podman run` command.

Comment: which port should i connect to for my connection string because it's not showing the port in the podman inspect